# unrecognized start character

Tags: javascript, pug

I'd like to set the attributes of an object using a variable which I read can be done with [`&attributes`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes), but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
- var attributes = { type: 'text' };
input&attributes
```

Should produce:

```
<input type="text" />
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
unrecognized start character
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually pass your `attributes` variable into `&attributes`:

```
- var attributes = { type: 'text' };
input&attributes(attributes)
```